# How to set Item checked in a checkedlistbox based on Key value?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have checkedListbox for which i am binding values with Id and Values, when the items are checked i'm saving the Id's in the database, when the form loads i want the checkedListbox items to be checked based on the Id's

I am only able to bind the checkedlistbox based on the index as below , the other alternative i see is getting the Index of the value and checking it but this will not work in my case as i have only the Id's of the checkedlistbox items which needs to be checked.

```
int index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf("42");
checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index , true);
```

this is how I am binding values

```
ccBoxitem item = new ccBoxitem(a.name, a.id);
checkedListBox1.items.add(item);
public ccBoxitem (string name, int val)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.val = val;
}
```

How can I check the `checkedlistbox` based on the id's ?

Comment: What is `Id of checkedlistbox item`?

Comment: updated my post

Comment: So `val` is an `id`?

Comment: yes val is an Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can loop through your items, then check the one you want:

```
 private void CheckItem(int id)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
     {
         if ((checkedListBox1.Items[i] as ccBoxitem)?.val == id)
         {
             checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
         }
     }
 }
```

usage:

```
var id = GetId();
CheckItem(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method it will select needed item by its value first then check the selected item

```
void CheckItem(CheckedListBox checkedListBox, int id)
{
    checkedListBox.SelectedItem = checkedListBox.Items.OfType<ccBoxitem>().ToList().FirstOrDefault(i => i.val == id);
    checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox.SelectedIndex, true);
    checkedListBox.SelectedItem = null; // To clear selection if needed
}
```

And you can call it as below

```
CheckItem(checkedListBox1, 3);

CheckItem(checkedListBox1, 6);
```